# What word will you use for this

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

There’s this word in Spanish which mean someone who asks a lot from others “pediche” an example would be my dogs, they always want food and stare at me asking me for it so i say “son un pair de pediches” “you are a pair of...”
Or my friend who always asks for my school supplies like pens, erasers, glue etc “ximena es una pediche siempre me pide” (ximena is a... she always asks me for things”

Answer (score 2):

"Beggar/to beg" is a word I frequently use with my cats, who know they get some of whatever I'm eating:

> Hey! Stop **begging**!  It's just a banana, not something you want.

"Moocher/to mooch" is a slang term for someone who begs or borrows things repeatedly from other people, generally with no intention to return or repay the favor.

> She's always **mooching** my cookies when I bring them into the office.  I wish she'd buy her own.